# API and Clio Manage

Tags: clio-api

I'm trying to implement OAuth flow for [Clio API](https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation). During OAuth process it sends me to Clio Manage login page and I'm unable to login into it. At the same time I can login to https://eu.app.clio.com/ using same credentials.

The question is for the people who already made integration with Clio: did you used trial account or maybe you had paid account? I'm not sure if I need paid account for Clio API integration (Clio Manage login). I sent my question to Clio support but I do not have a lot of time and want to ask the same here...

Answer (score 2):

For USA and Europe there are different auth-point.
If can login to https://eu.app.clio.com/ , try connect:

```
   "BaseUrl": "https://eu.app.clio.com/api/v4/",
   "CallbackUrl": "https://app.clio.com/oauth/approval",
   "AuthUrl": "https://eu.app.clio.com/oauth/authorize",
   "TokenUrl": "https://eu.app.clio.com/oauth/token"
```

If can login to https://app.clio.com/ , try connect:

```
 "BaseUrl": "https://app.clio.com/api/v4/",
 "CallbackUrl": "https://app.clio.com/oauth/approval",
 "AuthUrl": "https://app.clio.com/oauth/authorize",
 "TokenUrl": "https://app.clio.com/oauth/token"
```

Answer (score 1):

Clio support sent me the next link: https://support.clio.com/hc/en-us/articles/203163300-Clio-API. This link tells me that unfortunately I do not have access to API in trial

Comment: I had same issue, logging into the link goes around in circles. The thing is, they do state in other places that you can do anything with the trial account that you can do with the paid account. So that's annoying. Doesn't help developers wanting to create apps.